# передача данных SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

мне надо из одной активности взять данные и сохранить их, а на другой активности их вывести. Не факт что активности будут идти друг за другом, поэтому метод intent не работает. Я сделал Prefences в одной активности, чтобы я мог сохранить и загрузить данные в одну и туже активность, но у меня не получилось передать данные. Я знаю что надо использовать getSharedPreferences ,но у меня не получилось его вписать чтобы он работал. Если можете, то сделайте пример кода для отпраляющей активности и для получающей.

Comment: да ну полно же в сети примеров кода

Comment: да плохо я ищу, не нашел хороший пример

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В отправляющей активности вы пишете данные:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.commit();
```

а в принимающей вы считываете:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String data = sharedpreferences.getString (String key, String defValue);
```

вот есть хороший [туториал](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php) и [документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)